# How to embed CHM file in application

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, chm

Hey everyone,
I just finished up an application I've been working on for a while now. Probably the most complex one I've made to date. Due to this, I figured I'd go and make a help document to provide users with some info on it.

I've created a CHM file, and set up a helpProvider, however now my problem is how to include this and the HHC (Table of contents) file with my application. I feel like it'd be a pain to require the user to copy the two files themselves, so I'm trying to store them as embedded resources, then have the application write these out in the current directory.

Currently, this is the code I'm using:

```
var data = Properties.Resources.RERHelp;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("RERHelp", FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Count() - 1);
            stream.Flush();
        }
        helpProvider1.HelpNamespace = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\RERHelp\\RERHelp.chm";
```

This works just fine, but it means I'd have to run through this twice, once with data set to Properties.Resources.RERHelp, and once for the Table of Contents file. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps some way to embed the CHM and HHC files in the application, and access them without writing them to disk? If that isn't possible, which I'm thinking it isn't, is there a better way to go about it than how I am currently?

Thanks for any help!

Best Regards,

Ian

Comment: Does the tool you are using have the ability to create static web pages instead of a CHM file?  The reason I ask is because CHM files can be a pain to deal with if you ever need to implement context sensitive help or if you don't have an installer.

Comment: What tool are you referring to? I suppose I could just create a new form with a WebBrowser control and have that load the separate html files from an embedded resource. I just found the native Help class to be easier to implement. I don't plan to implement context sensitive help, and I'm trying to avoid the need for an installer.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using a tool then to create the CHM file so all the more reason you might want to consider migrating to static HTML web based help.  There are numerous tools that can take an existing CHM file and convert them into HTML files but at first glance I can't seem to find any freeware or opensource offerings.

Comment: Oh you mean the tool to create the CHM. For that I just used Microsoft's HTML Help Workshop. I guess that's a viable alternative as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, wow. Turns out I didn't need the HHC file as well. I assumed I did because when I'd open the help dialog, it would say that it couldn't find the table of contents.hhc file. I assumed for some reason it needed that in addition to the CHM. I originally just made a method to pass the resources to so as to prevent redundancy, and called that once for the CHM, and once for the HHC, but then I noticed this bit:

```
data.Count() - 1
```

I'm not sure why that - 1 was there, the solution I found had it, so I just left it there. When I removed that, the program ran, wrote out that file, and could then read it for the help documentation without the complaint of the missing HHC. All is well. Thanks for the suggestions, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Apps usually use an installer, or zip archive of some sort. Both methods would allow a user to receive the application *and* the help files, without having to provide them separately.

Comment: I've never written an application that really merited an installer before, as there's nothing more than the executable. This is still one such application. It seems like overkill to have a user run an installer in order to extract an exe and two other files.

Comment: @Omega192: Then give them a ZIP file.

Comment: Unless I hear of otherwise, that'll have to do. I had hoped there was a way to keep this all within the single EXE file.

Comment: I'd recommend giving the user the option to download the zip of the exe and help, the exe as a standalone, and the chm as a standalone. That way the user can download what they need.

Comment: CHM's in zip files are not ideal, since they need to be unlocked to be viewed in windows. (all internet content downloaded by afaik all major browsers is flagged as potentially dangerous on windows xpsp2+ using alternate filestreams) Definitely go with an installer.

Answer (score 1):

So a solution is:
1) Copy your chm file to the required project folder
2) In your Visual C# solution explorer add existing item to the project (your chm file).
3) Select the Project menu then project properties.
4) Add existing resource.
5) Add the below code and connect to your help menu item.

```
   private void WORKING_HELP()
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\BlitzHelp.chm";

        try
        {
            //Check if already exists before making
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                var data = Properties.Resources.BlitzHelp;
                using (var stream = new FileStream("BlitzHelp.chm", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Count());
                    stream.Flush();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("file made");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //May already be opened

        }

        Help.ShowHelp(this, filePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Under your project properties - Resources, add a file resource ie:textmag.chm. I use filetype Text for the chm's

```
private void HelpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string helpFileName = "";
        try
        {
            helpFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources") + @"\TextMag.chm";
            Help.ShowHelp(this, helpFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string xxx = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Important: in the properties of the chm file under resources, the Build Action must be Content.